# Не работает PHP PhantomJS на хостинге

Tags: php, phantomjs

Проблема заключается в следующем: установил php phantomjs на MAMP. Делал все по инструкции отсюда: [введите сюда описание ссылки](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/4.0/)

Все установилось и работает хорошо... Затем я скопировал файлы мой хостинг и работать все перестало. Сделал var_dump ответа сервера, я так понимаю, и получил следующее:

> object(JonnyW\PhantomJs\Http\Response)#156 (8) { ["headers"]=> NULL ["status"]=> NULL ["content"]=> NULL ["contentType"]=> NULL ["url"]=> NULL ["redirectURL"]=> NULL ["time"]=> NULL ["console"]=> NULL }

Почему оно может не работать, и собственно все возвращаемые значения 0? Мой код ниже:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

$client = Client::getInstance();

$request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest('http://jonnyw.me', 'GET');

$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

var_dump($response);

$client->send($request, $response);


echo $response->getContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

Если верить исходникам https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs/blob/master/src/JonnyW/PhantomJs/Procedure/Procedure.php#L106,

то скорее всего проблема или с  http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php

не исключено что http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen тоже может влиять (здесь могу  врать).

Варианты:

1. Попросить хостера отключить safe-mode (включить allow-url-fopen)
2. Использовать другую библиотеку у которой нет данной проблемы
3. Хостить самому на виртуальном/железном сервере (aws/openshift/digitalocean ...)